# c# implementing IEqualityComparer<T> for generic class T

Tags: c#, generics, iequalitycomparer

Is there any way of implementing IEqualityComparer for generic class?

I tried:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyGenericClass>
```

which is wrong, because MyGenericClass takes 3 arguments as a generics, so next one

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyGenericClass<A, B, C>>
```

which is wrong, because I don't know types A,B,C. And so

```
public class MyComparer<MyGenericClass<A, B, C>> : IEqualityComparer<MyGenericClass<A, B, C>>
```

is wrong. Is there a way of implementing this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close

```
public class MyComparer<A, B, C> : IEqualityComparer<MyGenericClass<A, B, C>>
```

Side note, please don't name things A, B, and C.  That doesn't help anyone.  Standard naming convention is `T<SomethingDescriptive>`.  In the case of EF, it might be `TEntity`, in MVC or MVVM, it might be `TModel` or `TViewModel`.

Comment: ok, I promise I will never name things as A,B,C ever again. Btw thanks, I would never figure it out :)

Comment: Might also be good to note type constraints for these to make sure you are passing what you want in:
public class MyComparer<A, B, C> : IEqualityComparer<MyGenericClass<A, B, C>> 
where A : SomeInterface
where B : SomeOtherInterface
where C : AThirdInterface

These can be interfaces, base classes, or just new {}/Class. Very helpful for intellisense and accessing properties without a cast.